# UnauthorizedAccessException and with some string manipulation

Tags: c#

```
getFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(txt_Path.Text, "*.ini", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The above code give the below error if the program tries to access some secured folders i want to skip those type of folders.How can i do it.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

2nd problem :

In the below code(Which is present in a textdocument) i want to search google.com is exists or not where line starts with SiteURL=

or
want to get the text where both google.com and siteurl present in one line....

I tried some ways but it didnt give me any result...Can some one tell me working code for this and i am coding this tool in c# windows forms.

```html
    [Wordlist]
A18C49AFC938C293BE6A5BAC64363FF0=1
[Settings]
blnNoProxies=0
SiteURL=http://members.google.com/?id=noadvert
Timeout=10
WaitBot=0
ResolveHost=0
ProxyActivate=10
ProxyRatio=4
ProxyCombo=0
WaitTime=5
BanWindowWidth=1
BanWindowRatio=10
BanWindowProxies=10
RequestMethod=1
HTTPHeader=GET http://google.com/?id=noadvert HTTP/1.0|Accept: */*|User-Agent: <USER AGENT>|Host: m|Pragma: no-cache|Authorization: Basic <COMBO>|
UserPass=0
ComboFilter=0
ComboMode=0
UsernameStart=6
UsernameEnd=8
InvalidChars=
AllowedChars=
Letters=0
Digits=0
Alpha=0
LowerUpper=0
LetterDigit=0
SpeciaChar=0
PasswordStart=6
PasswordEnd=8
PasswordInvalidChars=
PasswordAllowedChars=
PasswordLetters=0
PasswordDigits=0
PasswordAlpha=0
PasswordLowerUpper=0
PasswordLetterDigit=0
PasswordSpeciaChar=0
[Keywords]
EnableHeaderSuccess=0
EnableHeaderBan=0
EnableHeaderFail=0
EnableHeaderRetry=0
HeaderSuccess=
HeaderBan=
HeaderFail=
HeaderRetry=
EnableGlobalSourceRetry=1
EnableSourceSuccess=1
EnableSourceBan=0
EnableSourceFail=0
EnableSourceRetry=0
SourceSuccess=<title>]a</title>
SourceBan=
SourceFail=
SourceRetry=
[Fake]
blnSuccess=0
SuccessRetries=3
blnCompleteNot=1
AfterFP=1
Success=3
blnInvalidPath=1
EnableConHits=0
ConHits=0
KeysOnIA=0
FollowRedirect=0
EnableConLength=0
ConLength=-1
SourceTags=1
[Ajax]
Variables=
PostElements=
RedURL=
[Form]
blnBasic=0
```

Comment: I solved the 2nd problem,Please help me to solve the first one.Thanks

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do here? Forgive me, but it looks a little suspicious.

Comment: No suspicious, I am just making a tool that search some ini files in certain folder but the tool search inside of each txt.This is a small project i taken one of my client.What ever coders have to code everything but use it in good way. :)

Comment: ANy way i solved the both the issues.Thanks